# Player crash when loading Flex application using SWFLoader

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash

I have a very simple Flex 4 app, the mxml of which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo"
  minWidth="400" minHeight="300">
  <fx:Script>
      <![CDATA[
          import mx.controls.Alert;

          public function Execute(foo:Object):void {
              Alert.show("Hello World");
          }
      ]]>
  </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

I am compiling this using `flex/bin/mxmlc file.mxml`.

In another Flex app, I am attempting to load the app above using an SWFLoader, and to run the `Execute` function. It's code looks similar to:

```
var swfLoader:SWFLoader = ...;
// on load, run the below
var loadedSM:SystemManager = SystemManager(swfLoader.content);
var loadedApp:Object = loadedSM.application;
loadedApp.Execute(this);
```

The outer app is loaded just fine by the browser, but when the SWFLoader loads the inner app, the outer app crashes / unloads: the browser window goes white.

In the debug log from Flash Player, this is what I see:

```
VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of getElementNearestScrollPosition in spark.layouts.HorizontalLayout.

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable ImageSkin__embed_mxml_Assets_swf___brokenImage_818059060 is not defined.

ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable _0c91adc980e321d1cb58dff2b8f06798859d4954576f5b2afe24ac0f6c486f60_flash_display_Sprite is not defined.
```

Any pointers at all?

Answer (score 0):

Within an application, you use the [spark:ModuleLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/modules/ModuleLoader.html) to load spark modules or applications (spark:Module or spark:Application). This takes care of the dependencies, as well as, the loading process.